# Splitting a csv file with OrderedDict elements in python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a a csv file with columns that are arrays of orderedDicts. For example, below is a column.

```
[OrderedDict([('@href', 'https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/scopus_id/0017048125'), ('@rel', 'self')]), OrderedDict([('@href', 'https://www.scopus.com/inward/record.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&scp=0017048125&origin=inward'), ('@rel', 'scopus')]), OrderedDict([('@href', 'https://www.scopus.com/inward/citedby.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&scp=0017048125&origin=inward'), ('@rel', 'scopus-citedby')])]
```

When I use csv reader and split at the commas, this element also splits. Since the data didn't wrap these elements within quotes, I have had trouble splitting this. I was thinking of writing my own function to split it at the commas and then combine the OrderedDict Items together. However, that might be inefficient and tedious. Is there a better way to do this? Possibly with regex?

Comment: You could go the streaming approach and use a stack to keep track of opening braces/brackets/parentheses. Then as you come across closing braces/brackets/parentheses, pop off the stack only if the pairs match. Then when your stack is zero, you know the next comma is the separator. Of course you'd want to keep track of when you're inside a string so you can ignore those.

Comment: Assuming your format is always consistent with the above, this should work: `(?:(?:OrderedDict\(\[\('[^']+', '[^']+'\), \('[^']+', '[^']+'\)\]\))(?:[,\]]))+`

Comment: You say that is a column? Did you mean row? If that is in your text file, it is not a CSV file, it a textual representation of a list of ordered dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have multiple lines in a file of the format you have given, rather than trying to use a regular expression to try and extract the information, you could (with extreme care) use Python's `exec()` function to load each row into a Python variable:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('input.txt') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        exec("row = " + line)

        for od in row:    # loop over each OrderedDict in the row
            print(f"{od['@rel']:20}  {od['@href']} ")
```

So if `input.txt` contained just one line (as above), this would output:

```
self                  https://api.elsevier.com/content/abstract/scopus_id/0017048125 
scopus                https://www.scopus.com/inward/record.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&scp=0017048125&origin=inward 
scopus-citedby        https://www.scopus.com/inward/citedby.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&scp=0017048125&origin=inward
```

Note: using `exec()` should be done with care. You should ensure that your source data does not contain any potentially malicious entries.

It might also help if you post a link to a copy of your actual file (or at least one containing multiple sample rows), you could use a service such as [0bin](https://0bin.net/).